# Как правильно експортнуть классы чтобы не ругался ESlint?

Tags: javascript, eslint

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таком виде всё работает. Но как только я меняю строку:

```
module.exports = {Shape, Rectangle, Triangle, Trapeze, Arch};
```

на (советут eslint):

```
export default {Shape, Rectangle, Triangle, Trapeze, Arch};
```

Всё сыпется. Как правильно экспортнуть?

Comment: что значит сыпется? где запускал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если экспортируете несколько классов, то без `default`

```
export {Shape, Rectangle, Triangle, Trapeze, Arch};
```